# How to keep Maurycyw's StaggeredGridView position on setColumnCount when orientation changed

Tags: java, android, android-gridview, staggered-gridview

When the screen orientation changes I set the number of columns to 1 or 2 depending on orientation, however doing that resets the scroll position to the top. I want it to keep it's position (maurycyw's StaggeredGridView works as expected.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is a library-specific problem. In case anyone still using the library(maurycyw's StaggeredGridView from https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridView) and has problem refrain the position when orientation changed and set column count at the same time, here is a solution using Accelerometer. But keep in mind, not all device support Accelerometer.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String urls[] = {
            "http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6101/6853156632_6374976d38_c.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7232/6913504132_a0fce67a0e_c.jpg",
            "http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4133/5096108108_df62764fcc_b.jpg",
            "http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4074/4789681330_2e30dfcacb_b.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8208/8219397252_a04e2184b2.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8483/8218023445_02037c8fda.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8335/8144074340_38a4c622ab.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8060/8173387478_a117990661.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8056/8144042175_28c3564cd3.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8183/8088373701_c9281fc202.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8185/8081514424_270630b7a5.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8462/8005636463_0cb4ea6be2.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8306/7987149886_6535bf7055.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8444/7947923460_18ffdce3a5.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8182/7941954368_3c88ba4a28.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8304/7832284992_244762c43d.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8163/7709112696_3c7149a90a.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7127/7675112872_e92b1dbe35.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7111/7429651528_a23ebb0b8c.jpg",
            "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8288/7525381378_aa2917fa0e.jpg",
            "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5336/7384863678_5ef87814fe.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7102/7179457127_36e1cbaab7.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7086/7238812536_1334d78c05.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7243/7193236466_33a37765a4.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7251/7059629417_e0e96a4c46.jpg",
            "http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7084/6885444694_6272874cfc.jpg"
    };
    private StaggeredGridView mGridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) this.findViewById(R.id.sgv);
        int margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin);
        mGridView.setItemMargin(margin); // set the GridView margin
        mGridView.setPadding(margin, 0, margin, 0); // have the margin on the sides as well
        StaggeredAdapter adapter = new StaggeredAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.id.imageView1, urls);
        mGridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        initAccelerometer();
    }

    private void initAccelerometer() {
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor accelerometer = sensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer,SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        int currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        if (currentOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
            mGridView.setColumnCount(2);
            mGridView.invalidate();
        }else{
            mGridView.setColumnCount(1);
            mGridView.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

It is edited MainActivity from https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo

And add this in the Activity, on the Android Manifest:
`android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"`